# Portability of pthread and socket.h

Tags: c++, c, sockets, pthreads, portability

right now i am planning on programming a little server in C/C++. The destination for that software will be some kind of a linux server, so i thought programmin the server on linux would be the best idea. The problem is, that i own a MacBook (Air) and i set up a Linux VM but the IDE (Qt creator) is freaking me out, so that i thought about developing the server within Xcode and then, when finished compiling it within the VM. So i am wondering how high the grade of portability is when it comes to pthread and socket.h? If they are portable to a certain grade would you recommend me to develop in Xcode? (I am a kind of familar with Xcode because the client of the server will be an iOS app. Sorry for my poor english (I'm from GER) and (possibly) thanks for your comment :)

Comment: What language? C or C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a third party library such as `boost` that abstracts away the platform specific details of both the [threading library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) and [socket library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Linux and Mac OS X operating systems are both supported by boost.

My answer is `c++` specific, I see you've tagged the question with `c` as well.

Comment: Well, for threads the OP should use the built in C++11 threads if they're available, not boost.

Answer (score 0):

Although using Boost might make your life easier, to answer the question `<pthread.h>` and `<sys/socket.h>` are both standard POSIX headers and portable between POSIX systems such Mac OS X and GNU/Linux.  There might be things in the GNU headers which are non-standard extensions or part of a newer POSIX, so not supported by Mac OS X, but almost everything in `<pthread.h>` and `<sys/socket.h>` that is available on Mac OS X is also available on GNU/Linux and works the same.  To be certain, check to be sure you're only using portable POSIX features not platform-specific features, by reading the functions' man pages or check the [Single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix.org/version3/) online (that link is for an older version of POSIX which Mac OS X supports, GNU/Linux mostly conforms to the latest [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html) spec.)

See [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) and [`<pthread.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/pthread.h.html)

Be aware that Mac OS X supports the base POSIX spec but not all optional parts, e.g. it doesn't support the "Timers" option of POSIX 2001 (which is part of the base spec, i.e. not optional, in POSIX-2008)